# Easily retrieving all instance of a double nested model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, querying

I have `Account has_many Hotels` and `Hotel has_many Rooms`

Thus I can writte `account.hotels` to get all hotels of a specific account and `hotel.rooms` to get all rooms of a specific hotel.

What if I want to get all rooms of a specific account ? Is there an elegant way to do that with rails without having to loop through every hotel of the account and storing in an array for exemple ?
Something like `account.hotels.rooms` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `has_many :through` on [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :hotels
  has_many :rooms, through: :hotels
end
```

and then

```
account.rooms
```